# Using \lstnewenvironment input in a caption parameter

Tags: listings, captions, environments

I'm trying to create a new `\lstlisting` environment with an input that represents the caption. I'm trying to do the following, but I get a "suspected you have forgotten a }" error. Any advice?

```
\lstnewenvironment{textfile}[1]
{
\lstset{frame=shadowbox, caption=#1}
}
{
}
```

Here's how I am trying to use it:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{listings} % Used for code blocks

%% Format the captions
\usepackage{caption} % Caption package
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{ \color{white} }
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{
  \colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01 }{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}
  }
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{ font={tt}, labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{textfile}[results.txt]
Album of the year: 24K Magic - Bruno Mars
Song of the year: Despacito - Justin Bieber
Best Rap Song: HUMBLE. - Kendrick Lamar
\end{textfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is defined (but missing in the 'MWE') the `textfile` listings environment requires a mandatory argument, but in the document it is called with an optional `[...]` one -- this is a syntax error.

Correcting to use `{}` removes the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{listings} % Used for code blocks

%% Format the captions
\usepackage{caption} % Caption package
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{ \color{white} }
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{
  \colorbox[cmyk]{0.43, 0.35, 0.35,0.01 }{
    \parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3}
  }
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{ font={tt}, labelformat=empty}

\lstnewenvironment{textfile}[1]
{
\lstset{frame=shadowbox, caption=#1}
}
{
}

\begin{document}
\begin{textfile}{results.txt}
Album of the year: 24K Magic - Bruno Mars
Song of the year: Despacito - Justin Bieber
Best Rap Song: HUMBLE. - Kendrick Lamar
\end{textfile}
\end{document}
```